# How to check if a calendar event has been deleted when iterating through an array of id's in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar

I have a column of calendar ids in Google Sheets. I have a function that checks the status colour of each event by checking `calId.getEventById('calId[i]').getColor`()

[image]

I'm looking for two solutions, if possible.

1. How would I raise an alert on the user's end or satisfy an if statement, when the calendar event paired to the id being iterated has been deleted from the Google Calendar?
2. How can I continue the rest of the iterations even if one iteration calendar event has been deleted?

Currently when I run my function and the for loop encounters an ID that has been deleted I get error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "getColor" of null.`

My code is something like this:

```
//Iterates through the array of calendar Id's in Google Sheets. 
 for (i = 0; i < tasks.getLastRow(); i++){  
   //Skips interation if note is empty. 
   if(notes[i][0] == '')continue;  
   eventColr = calId.getEventById('notes[i][0]').getColor();
   array.push([i, eventColr]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the quick and dirty way is probably to just watch for that error with a try/catch. If you get that error store the name in an array and continue iterating through the rows. Once your calculations are completed you can send the array to a deleteRows function. Check the array, if the array has more than one in length iterate through it deleting the rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help.